# Developing hotel website

Tags: web-development, best-practices, google-maps

I know HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and some of PHP/MySQL. I've decided to create simple hotel website, just to exercise my skills, and to see what i can really do. 
I wrote concrete technical details of my website:

1. User database where users can register and log in to see their booked places.
2. Search that has criteria of A)cost B)facilities C)rating D) distance to the user entered place
3. Gallery of house's pictures
4. Transaction page (electronic payment, PayPal and etc.)
5. Calendar that shows which dates are reserved and which are not.
6. Ability to pass user entered info to google maps and show exact location on the map.
7. Reviewing, adding comments to rented room or house.

Questions:

1. Is there template or framework that i can take to develop tasks # 1,#2, and #5?
2. If there's no template, where should i start to code my own search that would fit my criteria?
3. How to pass arguments to google maps to show location of house? (Vague explanation is ok)
4. Can you give guidelines on how to code module of website to achieve task #7?
5. How do people usually do task #5? I mean do they take the piece of code or just write it by themselves?

Sorry for my english.I'm not a native speaker. If you think that this explanation is to vague or indefinite, please do not just close this topic. All i want is just some guidance, i've come to the point when i realized that i need to challenge myself, but before i do this, i need to get some advice.
Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought... if you are doing this as a learning exercise then may be you shouldn't use any frameworks (and certainly no templates)?

Comment: I thought i could look at template as guideline and instruction.

Comment: @kmaxat It's great that you're building a site to teach yourself web development. Unfortunately, your question is very general and hard to answer. From the [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq): 'If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.' I suggest reading some books on web development, researching your questions to solve as many as you can yourself, then asking here (or on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) if you still have a very specific question that we can help with.

Comment: There are "services" that will do most of this coding for you but then again would not teach yourself very much but if I was going to do alot of these type of sites I would use one that would handle the load for me and let me work on developing a good site for the client while I let the service do the programing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are a number of PHP frameworks that will do the low level work for getting data and displaying it.
2. See 1.
3. If you have a Google map which shows your house then click on the link icon at the top to get a version of it you can link to or embed.
4. Not easily.
5. If they are using a content management system then these have calendar modules available. You may find that someone's done a calendar module for the framework you choose.

Comment: Question 4 is a fairly common practise in PHP?

Comment: @Chris It might be 'fairly common', but it's not necessarily a trivial task to describe (in any detail) how it's done.

Comment: MySQL table with rows to contain name/email/reviewer ID, comment, date and room ID (to suit kmaxat's application). Basic HTML form to submit data to the database. Simple PHP to recall from the database.